# Create health check for angular application

Tags: angular

Devops team want a health url to check that angular application is UP by returning 200 as status code.

what we code is just adding a new route into our `app-routing.module.ts` as

```
{path: 'health', component: null}
```

as result the first time it return 200, then 304 as content has not modified.

What we need to modify to always return 200 as status code when calling /health ?

Answer (score 0):

The state 304 says:

> The content of the requested resource has not changed since the client's last query and is therefore not transferred.

The `component: null` in your router does not working (in Angular 15 it can't work: `(property) Route.component?: Type<any> | undefined`. So null not working. And a `undefined` answer always `status 404`.

So you can do the follow:

- Accept status 200 **and** 304
- Build a little page, blank. (I think it's enough)
- return a random number an the blank page.

Note: I don't know with which technic you work, but Docker, or K8s check the health by self.

In the end I think the problem is your **null** page you return.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304).